ERROR gradlew failed when converting .py to .apk with buildozer
Greetings to the community.
Please I am new to programming, I am running Arch Linux and this my first conversion of kivymd app to android. First my folder contained main.py and MyApp.kv then i created venv with:
$ python -m venv venv  
$ pip install buildozer  

My pip freeze looks like this:
appdirs==1.4.4
build==1.2.1
buildozer @ https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/archive/master.zip#sha256=6c6c2f149766d7132576317a9295f13849524           2ccca1283282c100826a510ee6f
colorama==0.4.6
Cython==0.29.37
distlib==0.3.8
filelock==3.14.0
Jinja2==3.1.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
packaging==24.0
pexpect==4.9.0
platformdirs==4.2.1
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pyproject_hooks==1.1.0
setuptools==69.5.1`
sh==1.14.3
toml==0.10.2
virtualenv==20.26.1

`
I have run:
$ buildozer init
directory now looks like this:
.  ..  bin  .buildozer  buildozer.spec  main.py  Myapp.kv  venv
I now run:
$ buildozer android debug deploy run
The Error then looks like this:
[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/nemesis/Myapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/firstandroidapp/gradlew failed!
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
Warning: failed to apply patch (exit code 1), assuming it is already applied:  src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
# Command failed: ('/home/nemesis/Myapp/venv/bin/python', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'apk', '--bootstrap', 'sdl2', '--dist_name', 'firstandroidapp', '--name', 'First Android App', '--version', '0.1', '--package', 'org.test.firstandroidapp', '--minsdk', '21', '--ndk-api', '21', '--private', '/home/nemesis/Myapp/.buildozer/android/app', '--android-entrypoint', 'org.kivy.android.PythonActivity', '--android-apptheme', '@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar', '--orientation', 'portrait', '--window', '--enable-androidx', '--copy-libs', '--arch', 'arm64-v8a', '--arch', 'armeabi-v7a', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/nemesis/Myapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug')
# Error code: 1
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/Nemesis:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1446,unix/Nemesis:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1446'
#     WINDOWID = '83888394'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg'
#     NVM_INC = '/home/nemesis/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/include/node'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'xfce-'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/tmp/ssh-XXXXXX9lCn1f/agent.1476'
#     CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY = '/run/credentials/getty@tty1.service'
#     MEMORY_PRESSURE_WRITE = 'c29tZSAyMDAwMDAgMjAwMDAwMAA='
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'xfce'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1480'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'canberra-gtk-module:canberra-gtk-module'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     PWD = '/home/nemesis/Myapp'
#     LOGNAME = 'nemesis'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'tty'
#     SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID = '957'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/nemesis/.Xauthority'
#     WINDOWPATH = '1'
#     MOTD_SHOWN = 'pam'
#     HOME = '/home/nemesis'
#     LANG = 'de_DE.UTF-8'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'XFCE'
#     VIRTUAL_ENV = '/home/nemesis/Myapp/venv'
#     MEMORY_PRESSURE_WATCH = '/sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/system-getty.slice/getty@tty1.service/memory.pressure'
#     VTE_VERSION = '7600'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '330fcc46d5d444069bb9a10f86d0cf69'
#     NVM_DIR = '/home/nemesis/.nvm'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     USER = 'nemesis'
#     DISPLAY = ':0.0'
#     SHLVL = '4'
#     NVM_CD_FLAGS = ''
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XDG_VTNR = '1'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '1'
#     VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT = '(venv) '
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     PS1 = '(venv) [\\u@\\h \\W]\\$ '
#     DEBUGINFOD_URLS = 'https://debuginfod.archlinux.org '
#     GTK3_MODULES = 'xapp-gtk3-module:xapp-gtk3-module'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share'
#     PATH = '/home/nemesis/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/nemesis/Myapp/venv/bin:/home/nemesis/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/nemesis/.local/bin:/home/nemesis/.local/bin:/home/nemesis/.local/bin'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     NVM_BIN = '/home/nemesis/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin'
#     MAIL = '/var/spool/mail/nemesis'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/nemesis/Myapp/.buildozer'
#     _ = '/home/nemesis/Myapp/venv/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/nemesis/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/nemesis/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/nemesis/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2



I have checked online but no similar errors other gradlew failed errors are different.
